# Lightning:input required="true" is not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, fields, lightninginput, required-field

I'm using a required field for an aura component that should does not save a record if any of required fields is missing.

This is my input:

```
<lightning:input aura:id="test" name="test" required="true" value=""
                        label="Test" />
```

My save record button:

```
<lightning:button variant="Brand" label="Add" title="Add"
                        onclick="{!c.createDoc}" />
```

And this is my JS controller:

```
createDoc: function (cmp) {
        
        var test = cmp.find("test").get('v.value');
        var action = cmp.get("c.createDocCtrl");

        action.setParams({

            test: test

        });
        
        action.setCallback(this, function (response) {

            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                
                var wrapper = response.getReturnValue();
                var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                toastEvent.setParams({
                    "type": "success",
                    "message": "success"
                });
                toastEvent.fire();
                $A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();
            } else {
                
                var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                toastEvent.setParams({
                    "type": "error",
                    "title": "error",
                    "message": response.getError()
                });
                toastEvent.fire();
            }
            
        });
        
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
```

So... the problem is that, if I leave the required field blank, it runs anyway. So, I need to make any logic on my controller that avoids that user could save records if required field is null or blank.

Comment: have you tried anything to prevent the callback from firing? where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting required to true doesn't prevent buttons from working; you still need to do your own validation. This is called out in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_validate_fields.htm).

```
({
    handleCreateContact: function(component, event) {
        var allValid = component.find('contact').reduce(function (validSoFar, inputCmp) {
            inputCmp.reportValidity();
            return validSoFar && inputCmp.checkValidity();
        }, true);

        if (allValid) {
        /******** Insert code from "Creating a Form" topic ********/
        var saveContactAction = component.get("c.createContact");
            saveContactAction.setParams({
                "contact": component.get("v.newContact")
            });
        
        // Configure the response handler for the action
            saveContactAction.setCallback(this, function(response) {
                var state = response.getState();
                if(state === "SUCCESS") {
                    component.set("v.message", "Contact created successfully");
                }
                else if (state === "ERROR") {
                    console.log('Problem saving contact, response state: ' + state);
                }
                else {
                    console.log('Unknown problem, response state: ' + state);
                }
            });
 
            // Send the request to create the new contact
            $A.enqueueAction(saveContactAction);
            /******** End code from "Creating a Form" topic ********/
        } else {
            alert('Please update the invalid form entries and try again.');
        }
        
    },
})
```